# Change my plugin folder name at wordpress subversion (using TortoiseSVN)

Tags: wordpress, svn, plugins, tortoisesvn, rename

I wrote a pluginfor wordpress and used TotrtoiseSVN (from Windows) to move my plugin files and folders to wordpress.org subversion. Although the name of the plugin is wp_myPlugin and the folder that contains the files should be wp_myPlugin, somehow the '_' has changed to '-'???

So now when someone downloads my plugin he gets 'wp-myPlugin.zip' which will not work.

Is there a way to correct this with TortoiseSVN (not good at terminal and commands) ?

If there is no way to chenge it, do you recommend making a new version, which will allow the plugin to work with 'wp-myPlugin' ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up adding a new version of the plugin, which uses 'wp-myPlugin' as root folder.